# centering images by HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html, qualtrics

I'm trying to center an image on Qualtrics. I tried a lot of codes I found, but nothing works.

Examples of what I already tried:

```
<style>
    .img-container {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }
</style>




.center {   
    display: block;   
    margin-left: auto;   
    margin-right: auto; 
 }



<style> 
    .ChoiceStructure {     
        text-align: center;
    } 
</style>
```

The preference is to use HTML or JavaScript rather than CSS because the center is for a specific question.

In the question, the URL of the images appears in LOOP & MERGE so I do not have the specific name of the image to write in the code.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The simplified example below uses `flex` and `justify-content`.

In your case, it's not `div` but `.img-container` that you probably need to use for the container.

The `span` style rule is just a simple example and you don't need that at all.

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

span {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<div>
<span></span>
</div>
```

So, in your case it should be:

```
.img-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: thank you! maybe you can guide me where I have to write each part?